# How to create ant XSLT report using Jmeter 3.0?

Tags: jmeter

I have to move my jmeter scripts from 2.13 version to 3.0. we are using ant xslt reports for functional testing report format. Can anyone help me how to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl` file does not exist any more, you either need to copy it from [JMeter 2.13 bundle](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.13.zip) (lives in "extras" folder) or update your .xsl file(s) to use `jmeter-results-detail-report.xsl` instead.

Just in case see [Visualizing JMeter .jtl Files Viewed as An .xsl Stylesheet](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/visualizing-jmeter-jtl-files-viewed-xsl-stylesheet) article for details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dmitri. I have copied the jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl file to jmeter 3.0 extras folder and it is working fine.